# Google Form dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy date format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

My google form has a date question and it always shows as dd/mm/yyyy,

[image: Date question on google form]

although the format that goes to my spreadsheet is **mm/dd/yyyy** which is **correct**. Is there a way to change it to show as mm/dd/yyyy whenever I view the form?

Comment: Probably has something to do with your ip address/browser/browser settings(language?)

Answer (score 0):

As [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777153/google-form-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-date-format#comment101992703_57777153) pointed out, the date displayed in the textbox is formatted according to your Google Account language settings. Yours is probably configured as English (<s>United States</s> UK).

You can change it [here](https://myaccount.google.com/language). Also, you might want to take a look at the [documentation](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047).

Comment: Which country should I use to change it to mm/dd/yyyy? I tried English (United Kingdom) but it's still the same.

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with Chrome ignoring the Local zone browser configuration. Check if you have the same issue with another browser.